# WPF Toolkit Datagrid Bug

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, wpftoolkit, toolkit

i have a tab control with 2 tabs. the content of each tab is binded to a ListCollectionView and the data template has a grid showing the items. The problem is that if you click on any of the columns to sort, if I select the other tab and return to the first tab the sorting is cleared. Is it a known bug?

here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
Title="Window1" Height="538" Width="1223">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate">
        <toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" IsReadOnly="True" >
            <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
                <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IntVal}" Header="Number"></toolkit:DataGridTextColumn>
                <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StringVal}" Header="String"></toolkit:DataGridTextColumn>
            </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        </toolkit:DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="tab1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TestTemplate}" x:Name="a" Content="{Binding}"/>
        <TabItem Header="tab2" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TestTemplate}" x:Name="b" Content="{Binding}"/>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

code behid:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<test> intt = new List<test> 
        {
            new test { IntVal = 5, StringVal = "abc" }, 
            new test { IntVal = 12, StringVal = "cc" }, 
            new test { IntVal = 2, StringVal = "sdgc" }, 
            new test{IntVal=64,StringVal="df"},
            new test{IntVal=1234,StringVal="werw"}, 
            new test{IntVal=14,StringVal="sdvvd"}, 
            new test{IntVal=136,StringVal="aasr"} 
        };

        List<test> intt2 = new List<test> 
        {
            new test { IntVal = 5, StringVal = "abc" }, 
            new test { IntVal = 12, StringVal = "cc" }, 
            new test { IntVal = 2, StringVal = "sdgc" }, 
            new test{IntVal=64,StringVal="df"},
            new test{IntVal=1234,StringVal="werw"}, 
            new test{IntVal=14,StringVal="sdvvd"}, 
            new test{IntVal=136,StringVal="aasr"} 
        };

        this.a.DataContext = new ListCollectionView(intt);
        this.b.DataContext = new ListCollectionView(intt2);
    }

    public class test
    {
        public int IntVal { get; set; }
        public string StringVal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the TabControl destroy and recreate its child every time you change the selected tab. That would explain why the sort is not kept.

You can check out [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/browse_thread/thread/6572f7781764f937/3b9e1d5579b8ff6d?lnk=gst&q=tab+control#3b9e1d5579b8ff6d) on the WPF Disciples Google Group to have some infos about how to fix that problem.

Comment: Thanks

I will give it a test and see if it helps.

Although it does work when you hard code the datagrid in the tab. I guess that the tab creates everything from scratch only if you use a template

Answer (score 0):

I had ran into a similar issue. I think wpf uses the same contentpresenter for data templates. In your case instance of the datagrid is the same, only data is rebound when you switch tabs. 
What I did was to create an instance of the control in codebehind and set it as a content property of the TabItem.
e.g

```
TabItem ti = new TabItem();
ti.DataContext = intt;
ti.Content = new DataGrid();
myTabControl.Items.Add(t);
```

hope this helps..